# Isomorphism between semidirect products

Tags: group-theory

Alperin and Bell, Groups and Representations, section 2, Proposition 11, p. 23, states:
"Let $H$ be a cyclic group and let $N$ be an arbitrary group. If $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are monomorphisms from $H$ to Aut($N$) such that $\varphi(H) = \psi(H)$, then we have $N \underset{\varphi}{\ltimes} H \cong N \underset{\psi}{\ltimes} H$."

If I'm not wrong, the hypothesis that $H$ is cyclic is unnecessary, because there exists an automorphism $g$ of $H$ such that $\varphi = \psi \circ g$, so that $(n, h) \mapsto (n, g(h))$ defines an isorphism from $N \underset{\varphi}{\ltimes} H$ onto $N \underset{\psi}{\ltimes} H$.

Do you know a source where the proposition is stated without the assumption that $H$ is cyclic ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $\varphi_{0}$ the isomorphism fom $H$ onto $\varphi (H) = \psi(H)$ that sends an element $h$ of $H$ to $\varphi(h)$. Define similarly an isomorphism $\psi_{0}$ from $H$ onto $\varphi (H) = \psi(H)$. Put $g = \psi_{0}^{-1} \circ \varphi_{0}$. Isn't $g$ an automorphism of $H$ with the required property ?

Comment: I agree with panurge on this. The fact that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are both monomorphisms implies that the automorphism exists. It is a standard result that the semidirect products defined by two homomorphisms $\varphi,\psi: H \to {\rm Aut}(N)$ that differ by composition by an automorphism of $H$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I got confused.